# Trying to use Twitter from console application.Credentials somehow are stored the wrong way

Tags: c#, twitter, trim, tweetinvi

I made a console application usin Tweetinvi c# library. My project is almost complete if i solve this problem.

Everytime I use Tweetinvi and set the credentials typing the keys directly into the code it works fine and publishes tweets so I know that command works. However I need to store the credentials in a file parse them to substring and clear them from spaces etc.Parsing is successful since i checked with `console.writeline`. When use variables to set the keys in tweetinvi authoriatization nothing happens wich mean I 'm making a mistake when clearing my substrings. `Consolle.Writelines` shows nothing and credentials dont work.Any help?`

```
{                           
    AccessToken = AccessToken.Replace(@"\r\n", "");
    AccessToken = AccessToken.Trim();
    Console.WriteLine(AccessToken);
    AccessTokenSec = AccessTokenSec.Replace(@"\r\n", "");
    AccessTokenSec = AccessTokenSec.Trim();
    Console.WriteLine(AccessTokenSec);
    var creds = new TwitterCredentials("consumerkei", "consumerkeysecret",AccessToken.Trim(),AccessTokenSec.Trim());
    Auth.SetCredentials(creds);
    var firstTweet = Tweet.PublishTweet("Hello World! Again!");
}
```

`